# Pythonpath get last part of path

Tags: python, jython

I dont want to use pathlib, so avoid answers with it

```
aString = "/test/test1/test2/test3"
aString = os.path(astring.parts[1:])
```

I want to get /test1/test2/test3 ,using import os or import os.path

Comment: Why would you not want to use pathlib, which is a standard Python library and the recommended way of dealing with something like this?

Comment: Do you want the last part of the path from the second slash?

Comment: Here is what I could come up with `os.path.join('/',*aString.split(os.path.sep)[2:])`

Comment: If you don't want to use any library, only way is like this: `aString[aString[1:].find('/')+1:]`

Comment: no pathlib, because i am writing a plugin for a tool called autopsy https://www.autopsy.com/ . Its written in jython, when i import pathlib it says no module named pathlib . i don't want to tell my users to install the library pathlib for it.

Comment: Note that Jython is Python 2.7. This question is tagged Python 3.X.

Comment: We also have Jython tag not to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can only use `os`, this may suit:

```
my_path = '/test1/test2/test3/test4'
os.path.sep.join(['']+my_path.split(os.path.sep)[2:])
```

Note that it takes `2:` because the root will be in the split as well, so it just adds that back in.

Also note that if your path is actually `/test1/test2/test3/test4`, then `/test2/test3/test4` seems an odd value, since it still starts at the root - you may want to check if that's really what you need.